# Allowing only contract B to call contract A

Tags: solidity, modifiers

I have a structure of the following form:

```
contract A {
    uint num;
    function setNum(uint target) public onlyB {
        num=target;
    }
}

contract B{...}
```

I want the modifier onlyB to check `require(msg.sender==address(B))`. Is the best practice to deploy B first and then hardcode B's address to A?

Comment: Yes, you deploy B first and hardcode its address into A. Recommended reading: [Smart Contract Orchestration Patterns](https://medium.com/coinmonks/smart-contract-orchestration-patterns-b9043b7c27c4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, or if you want to deploy B second, you have a way to change the B address in contract A

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to change B's address in A? One method that I know is to use proxy to make the contract upgradable.

Comment: I mean just in contract A have a function (say onlyOwner) that is:  changeContractBAddress(address _newAddy)